# Formula to Value when data entered in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

If I put a value on any cell under column B the macro will copy and paste as values the information on cell j & k that belongs to the same row as the active cell

for example if I type a value on b 10 and then hit the macro button j 10 &  k 10 change from formula to values.

I really want to do this automatically every time I enter a value on any cell under column B instead of hitting the button.

Please see below the current code for the macro I have

http://imageshack.com/f/exgUKSP0p

Comment: a) Be sure to include call to `application.enableevents = false` and then `application.enableevents = true` when processing is finished or the Worksheet_Change will try to run on top of itself. b) you are going to have to pass the target.row number into `MyMacro` so it knows what J & K to process. Cannot suggest anything without seeing at least part of MyMacro.

Comment: This is the macro I want to call by entering a value on any cell under column B

Sub Settime()
If ActiveCell = "" Then
MsgBox "Ingrese El account Number"
Else
Range("J" & ActiveCell.Row & ":K" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
End Sub

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some fairly standard `Worksheet_Change` framework to get you started.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Columns("B"))
            If rng.Row > 2 Then ' your sample code seemed to suggest that this should start on row 3 and higher
                Call Settime(rng.Row)
            End If
        Next rng
    End If
Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub Settime(rw as long)
    If range("B" & rw) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Ingrese El account Number" 
    Else
        Range("J" & rw & ":K" & rw) = Range("J" & rw & ":K" & rw).value
    End If 
End Sub
```

I don't know if pasting a number of values into column B should be handled, but the above does take care of each value added/changed/deleted in turn. As mentioned in comments, you need to pass the target row into your macro so it knows what row to process in columns J and K. Whenever possible, try not to rely upon `ActiveCell` or `.Select` to determine what cell or range of cells is going to receive the processing.

Comment: Im not sure why is not working how can I give you the Mymacro code without pasting it here ? because when I paste it here it looks to Messy and my Macro name is Sub Settime()

Comment: @KarlD - Go back and [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29504774/edit) your question to include the code you want to run. The code as provided works at resolving the formulas in columns J and K to their values on the row(s) that change in column B.